# Reading list to master Numerical Analysis' research literature

Tags: stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

As of lately I have been going through many research papers in my current job, and even though I have a Mathematics background at Masters level in Mathematical Finance, I sometimes struggle to follow some arguments in numerical analysis.

The research always involves an stochastic component, as these papers are mainly related to Probability theory applied to finance. A clear example of the situation is [this paper](https://dspace.library.cornell.edu/bitstream/1813/9175/1/TR001295.pdf).

My question is mostly aimed at people who hold PhD degrees in Physics or Mathematics. Can you recommend me a well-respected book in numerical analysis that would help me better grasp the reasoning behind advanced numerical arguments like the paper above mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer to the following book.
[Non-Linear Option Pricing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1466570334) co-authored by Pierre Henry Labordere recipient of 'Quant of the year 2013'.

It clearly explains the BSDE approach to solve parabolic pdes of first and second order and draws out the discretization schema in detail. It also contains financial applications of this approach.

In addition to this, it contains several non-linear methods (HJB, stochastic control, particle method, optimal stopping time problem etc).

Edit:
Second reference

[Computational Methods in Finance](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439829578)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll definitely have a look. However, I was looking for a book that is not that much focused on BSDEs, rather advanced numerical analysis techniques.

Comment: [Computational Methods in Finance](http://www.amazon.com/Computational-Methods-Finance-Financial-Mathematics/dp/1439829578) is a very good resource for numerical techniques. Goes straight to the point and describes all the methods in detail. Although i highly suggest you read Non-Linear Option Pricing which is adaption of tools used in physics to finance and these books complement each other very well.

Comment: Cool I suppose this is enough to render the question answered ;)

Comment: Great that you found the answer useful. Implement every technique in a language of your choice. Its the one exercise that helped me understand the idea than staring at the pages for hours. Good luck.